HP Envy 16-h0959nz does not let me select the OS (Windows 11 or Ubuntu)
I have an HP Envy Laptop 16-h0959nz from 2023 that has Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 installed on it. As you can see in the below screen I have to escape the boot process so that I can select Ubuntu 24.04.

I wanted the dual boot for temporary purpose. In my opinion I don't need Windows anymore, but as you can see, I'm not in Windows. I still need it so that I can write a question here. The sound module isn't working properly either. I tried a lot of things half a year ago and I couldn't get it working.

The solution is really simple. You have to change the order of the two boot managers in the BIOS so that the Ubuntu boot manager, which also recognizes Windows (Grub), is started first.
After the change it should look something like this:

